# operator norm on $L^1$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that $\|T\| \ge 1$ when $T: L^1_{[0,1]} \to L^1_{[0,1]}$ is given as $T(f)(x) = \int_0^x f(y) dy$. I'm wondering if my approach is correct:

\begin{align*}
\|T\| &=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \left \| \int_0^x f(y)dy \right \|\\
&=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \int_0^1 \left | \int_0^x f(y)dy \right |dx\\
&=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \left |\int_0^1  \int_0^x f(y)dy dx \right |\\
&=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \left |\int_0^1  \int_0^1 1_{[0,x]}(y) f(y)dy dx \right |\\
&=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \left |\int_0^1  \int_0^1 1_{[0,x]}(y) f(y)dx dy \right | \qquad \text{(Fubini)}\\
&=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \left |\int_0^1 f(y) \int_0^1 1_{[y,1]}(x) dx dy \right | \\
&=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \left |\int_0^1 f(y) (1-y) dy \right | \\
&=\sup_{\|f\|=1} \int_0^1 |f(y)| (1-y) dy  \\
&=\|f \| - \sup_{\|f\|=1} \int_0^1 |f(y)|y dy  \\
\end{align*}

Not sure how to proceed or if this is the right path to take..

Comment: In the third equality, how do you move the absolute value?

Comment: I would try two inequalities instead of one identity: $\|Tf\|\leqslant \|f\|$ and $\|Tf\|\geqslant \|f\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually $\|T\|=1$.

First we have that
$$
(Tf)(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt
$$
and thus
$$
\|Tf\|_{L^1}=\Big|\int_0^1\Big|\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\,\Big|\,dx\,\Big|\le 
\Big|\int_0^1\Big(\int_0^1 |\,f(t)|\,dt\Big)\,dx\,\Big|=
 \|\,f\|_{L^1},
$$
and hence $\|T\|\le 1$.

Next set 
$$
f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
n & if & x\in[0,1/n], \\
0 & if & x\in(1/n,1].
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $\|\,f_n\|=1$ and
$$
(Tf_n)(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
nx & if & n\in[0,1/n], \\
1 & if & x\in(1/n,1],
\end{array}
\right.
$$ 
and $\|Tf_n\|=1-\frac{1}{2n}$. Hence
$$
\|T\|\ge \frac{\|Tf_n\|}{\|\,f_n\|}=1-\frac{1}{2n},
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and consequently $\|T\|\ge 1$.

Altogether, $\|T\|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your approach is useful. Let $f_n=nI_{(0,1/n)}$. Then $\|f_n||=1$ for all $n$ and $\|Tf_n\|=1-\frac 1 n +\frac 1 {2n} \to 1$. So $\|T\| \geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to give an example of a function f with norm 1 wrt L¹, where the antiderivative has norm bigger than 1. I would start with some examples and try to find a pattern.

[edit] as another user mentioned, the operator norm is indeed 1, so you would try to find an example where the norm of f is 1 and the norm of Tf is also 1. This would show your statement.